# Can a function have overlapping range?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Consider the function $f : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{align}x^2 - 2 & \text{if}\,x > 0,\\
x - 1 & \text{if}\, x \le 0.\end{align}\right.$$
Find a right inverse of $f$.

The answer that I came up to this question was this:

$$f(g(x)) = x$$
$$g(x) = \left\{\begin{align} \sqrt{x+2} & \text{if}\, x > -2,\\
x + 1 & \text{if}\, x\le -1.\end{align}\right.$$

However, the ranges $-1 \ge x > -2$ overlap. Since the definition of a function is that each $x$ maps to only 1 $y$, if $x = -1$ then there are potentially 2 $y$ that it could map to: $1$ and $0$. So is this therefore not a function? How can it not be the right answer?

Comment: The question asks you to give a function,any function, that can be a right inverse of $f$, but $g$ is not a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right in that your $g$ is not a function.

In the overlapping range, you need to decide which one of the two branches to choose.

**Solution**:

For example, you can choose
$$g(x)=\left\{\begin{align}\sqrt{x+2} & \text{if}\,x>-2\\
x+1 & \text{if}\,x\le -2\end{align}\right.$$

Now suppose that $x>-2$. Then $\sqrt{x+2}>0$ and therefore $f(g(x))=f(\sqrt{x+2})=(\sqrt{x+2})^2-2=x$.

Suppose that $x\le -2$. Then $x+1\le -1\le 0$. So $f(g(x))=f(x+1)=(x+1)-1=x$.

Altogether, $g$ is a right inverse of $f$.

In the range from $-2$ to $-1$ you are free to choose any of the two branches.

*Every* choice (even if it's different at every point, i.e. if you jump between branches all the time) will give you a right inverse.

Comment: does it matter if I set the x > -2 to x > -1 or set the x <= -1 to x <= -2 or is it the same?

Comment: Simply try both possibilities. You will see.

Comment: @user123542 in both cases your inverse will be an inverse. For non-monotonic function you don't have a unique inverse. Just try plotting $f(g(x))$ in both cases to see it's equal to $x$. In fact, you can split your $g(x)$ in any point between $-2$ and $-1$, not just at endpoints of the interval.